# AngularJS $compile is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I tried to convert string variable to html with angular, I get $compile component suggestion but something went wrong

My controller:

```
ChatZamba.controller("ScriptController", ['$scope', '$compile', function ($scope, $timeout, $compile) {
```

And My angular function:

```
function build_step_view(data, i){
    if(data != undefined){
        var tmp = $compile($('.detail-script-list'))(scope);
        $('.detail-script-list').append(tmp);
    }
}
```

But I get `TypeError: $compile is not a function` in Chrome complier when triggered my function.

Help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller code should be like:

```
ChatZamba.controller("ScriptController", ['$scope', '$timeout', '$compile', function ($scope, $timeout, $compile) {
}
```

You forgot to inject the reference of the $timeout service.