# How to Insert HTML with angularJS attribute in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, inject

I want to try:

```
function test(){
   $('#somediv').html('<div ng-model="name">{{name}}</div>');
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: jQueryish DOM manipulation isn't a good practice with Angular. You can use `ng-show/hide` and `ng-if` for this purpose instead

Answer (score 1):

When you add html which contains angular's built-in directives, you have to recompile it by `$compile` in order to let angular recognize.

refer the below code snippet.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.name = 'test value';
    $scope.test = function() {
      var element = angular.element($('#somediv'));
      element.html('<div ng-model="name">{{name}}</div>');
      $compile(element)($scope);
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="name">
  <button ng-click="test()">Add</button>
  <div id="somediv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$compile` service.

Just compile the html string like:

`var html = $compile('<div ng-model="name">{{name}}</div>')($scope);`

Don't forget to inject the `$compile` service into your controller.

Comment: Thank Hasan Ibrahim, I tried to do the same idea in my angular controller, but something went wrong :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603948/angularjs-compile-is-not-a-function

Comment: @NhạHoàng accept this one as well. Because this is the way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use jQuery DOM Manipulation in Angular, instead do something like:

```js
angular.module("main", []).controller("mainController", function($scope){

  $scope.toggle = function(){
  
    $scope.show = !$scope.show;
  
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="main"> 
<head> </head>


<body ng-controller="mainController">
<div>
<button ng-click="toggle()"> Toggle Div </button>


<div ng-if="show"> Div Contents </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```